# Referencing a file containing square brackets ([]) in its path

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm quite new to PowerShell, and I'm using the Get-Hash cmdlet:

This works:

```
PS M:\> Get-Hash -Path "C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\New Folder\database.adp" -Algorithm SHA512
```

This fails:

```
PS M:\> Get-Hash -Path "C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\New [Folder]\database.adp" -Algorithm SHA512
Get-Hash : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty array.
```

I understand this is likely due to the square brackets in the path `[]` which are valid under Windows operating systems.  So how do I get PowerShell to escape these?

Comment: This is a common question.  In powershell and .net the square brackets are used to make wildcards like `[0-9]*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use ` backtick to escape the square bracket and enclose the whole string in single quote.

```
PS M:\> Get-Hash -Path 'C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\New `[Folder`]\database.adp' -Algorithm SHA512
```

Comment: C:\Users\medmondson\Desktop\New `[Folder`]\database.adp unfortunately returns the same error message

Comment: Are you passing the path as a variable? And may be the variable is empty?  I created a similar folder and a file then used get-hash function and it worked.

Comment: You are right, this works.  I must have been doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use -LiteralPath instead -Path