# How to read file path where folder has square brackets in the name

Tags: c#, filepath, brackets, square

I have a file path as follows:

```
C:\Recordings\Public\20160901\[MYPC]
```

*I cannot change the format of the folders*

I am attempting to read the contents of the folder using the following code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(args[0], "*.*"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    Console.WriteLine(contents);
}
```

I am recieving the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
```

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660152/referencing-a-file-containing-square-brackets-in-its-path) as I have used this method with powershell previously and had great results, it does not appear to work with c# though. I am setting the read path via CMD line args[0] (console app)

Any ideas/pointers would be most welcome.

**UPDATE**

I was calling my application with the following which gave me an error:

```
myapp.exe "c:\My Recordings\Public\20160905\[CDPC]\"
```

The following did not:

```
myapp.exe "c:\My Recordings\Public\20160905\[CDPC]"
```

Comment: An ugly workaround is to prefix each instance of the bad characters with '\\' (this is just one character, escaped)

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue: it is working for me You don't need any special trick, just typing the path as argument in the command line

Comment: hmm...shouldn't it be args[1]? args[0] usually contains the file executable name

Comment: @Pikoh No it's args[0] ... Again, I'm testing that code and it is working indeed

Comment: @MachineLearning I am seeing this when I have the following: C:\Recordings\Public\20160901\[MYPC]\ i think it must be the trailing backslash. When I removed the backslash I didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: ok,didn't read it was a console app and was getting the args via the constructor. Anyway, it's also working for me

Comment: @Majickal seriously, it is not the trailing backslash. It works too

Comment: glad I ran into this issue though as other uses will be running the app, so I guess now I have proved I need to put protections in to avoid the issue I encountered, cheers

Comment: @Majickal Again it is working also with the final backslash. The issue is not due to what you write and what you show in your question

Comment: @MachineLearning it might be because it is encapsulated in double quotes due to a space in the actual directory name ie: myapp.exe "C:\My Recordings\Public\20160901\[MYPC]\" that is when I get the error

Comment: Correct. It'd be better to specify this in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the wrapping quotes, if they are present

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(args[0].Replace("\"",""), "*.*"))
            {
                string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                Console.WriteLine(contents);
            }
```

It can also be done (more precisely) with regular expression

```
Regex.Replace(args[0], "(^\")|(\"$)", "") //instead of args[0].Replace("\"","")
```